# c# set event when 32 textbox value change

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I have this function

```
public void calculateTotalFructiferous() { 
            totalFructiferous.Text = ....;
        }
```

and I have 32 textboxes. I want to fire that function whenever the value of each of the 32 changed. I search on google and I found that I have to use the event `downkey and upkey` but I am not sure which one exactly. plus I would like if there is a way to make 
this call in a **different thread** than the thread of the windows form .

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev that is my favorite solution, but my manager refused

Comment: Add a [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) listener to all of the text-boxes (the same handler can be used and the specific control accessed via the sender parameter). When a change occurs, call the appropriate function. If the TextBox controls are added to an Collection first (which might be beneficial anyway), or already are [exclusive] children of the same container, then the handler can be added to all the controls with a simple loop in the code-behind. Do *not* use a different thread.

Comment: @user2864740 do you mean to change my method's parameters to `object sender, EventArgs e` ? I don't know about this colllection you talked about

Comment: Also note that UI components such as `TextBox` must be handled in the UI thread or you'll run into issues such as illegal cross-thread calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use TextChanged event for all TextBoxes:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.TextChanged += TextChanged;
        textBox2.TextChanged += TextChanged;
    }


    private void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        string text = tb.Text;

        calculateTotalFructiferous(text);
    }

    public void calculateTotalFructiferous(string text) 
    { 
        totalFructiferous.Text = ....;
    }
}
```

When you have CPU intensive calculation you can use this:

```
public delegate void CalculateTotalFructiferousDelegate(string text);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.TextChanged += TextChanged;
        textBox2.TextChanged += TextChanged;
    }


    private void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        string text = tb.Text;

        //If it is a CPU intensive calculation
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //Do sometihing with text
            text = text.ToUpper();

            if (InvokeRequired)
                Invoke(new CalculateTotalFructiferousDelegate(calculateTotalFructiferous), text);
        });
    }

    public void calculateTotalFructiferous(string text)
    {
        totalFructiferous.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is what I am doing now but I think this is in the same thread as the form thread right?

Comment: Words like `thread` do not fit the bill for something this simple.

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent Do *not* use a thread for this. There is *no* reason, given the problem description.

Comment: If "totalFructiferous" is a UI control you need to set the text the same thread as it was created...